# does the isolation type get overridden by the calling procedure?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I have some C# code that executes the following within a transaction scope of **ReadCommitted**:

```
 using (var createTempTableCommand = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    createTempTableCommand.CommandText = createTempTableScript;
                    createTempTableCommand.Connection = omniaConnection;
                    createTempTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                foreach (var command in listOfSqlCommands)
                {
                    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dtResults);
                    }
                }
```

The above code will call stored procedures that call other stored procedures, and at certain levels of this hierarchy, the transaction isolation mode can be changed like:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
```

**What affect does changing the isolation level within the parent transaction have?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction isolation level specified within the stored procedure execution scope will take precedence over the current session isolation level for the duration of proc execution.  Like all `SET` statements within a proc, the value will revert to the former setting after proc execution. Below is a T-SQL script that illustrates this.  The same applies to TransactionScope.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Transaction_IsolationLevelExample
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
DBCC USEROPTIONS; 
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
DBCC USEROPTIONS; --shows READ COMMITTED
EXEC dbo.usp_test; --shows SERIALIZABLE
DBCC USEROPTIONS; --shows READ COMMITTED
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Only one of the isolation level options can be set at a time, and it remains set for that connection until it is explicitly changed.

However, as pointed out by @HABO:

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Also from the referenced article: "If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure returns control to the batch."